# "I second that motion" or "I second that notion"

Tags: american-english

Context:

We are purchasing a monitor and in an email someone wrote, "Bob, let's get two of these" and posted a URL.

If I were to followup, which would be more appropriate and why?

"I second that motion" or "I second that notion"?

Fact is, we can find plenty of books that say "second that notion" – in places like [*Ski* magazine](http://books.google.com/books?id=GLrryx_1nVYC&pg=PA116&dq=%22second%20that%20notion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HbNEUpXaL-nD4APL3YDADw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAzge):

> Lee Aaker, 57, of Mammoth, Calif, would second that notion. (2001)

or [political commentary](http://books.google.com/books?id=kEYhAQAAMAAJ&q=%22second%20that%20notion%22&dq=%22second%20that%20notion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kbNEUuf_OLSn4AOWkoFg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBTgK):

> Ollie North calls the CIA/cocaine story "absolute garbage." I second that notion for two reasons...

but [far more](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=second%20the%20idea,%20second%20the%20notion,%20second%20the%20motion&year_start=1930&year_end=2006&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) say "second that motion."

So, is *second that notion* a malapropism? Or just a lesser-used (but still valid) form?

Comment: I suppose that, for email, you could say, "I second that e-motion." Smokey Robinson would approve.

Comment: If I could +1 this, I would.

Edit:* I am new here, why am I being downvoted?

Comment: @J.R. beat me to it.

Comment: I suppose you could call it an [*eggcorn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's motion. It's more like the use of motion in law. It's a noun (i.e. you file a motion or move to do something). So if someone where to make a motion (make a suggestion), you would second it if you agree.

It's completely idiomatic, but that's the use of motion here; it's not a legal term.

> Me: I move that we go out for dinner.
>   You: I second that motion!

Comment: Don't you think _notion_ might work, too? If one can say, "I second that proposal," or "I second that idea," then I suppose "I second that notion" would be acceptable, too. From _Time_ magazine, 2000: "As if to second that idea, Bill Clinton's plan last week, in its focus on enlarging existing programs, endorsed the Gore approach." From _New Scientist_, 1982: "Fortunately for Iceland, none of the 10 nations that voted for the zero quota felt able to second that proposal in plenary session, so the quota of 100 remains in force."

Answer (score 4):

The correct phrase is "second that motion". It originates from parliamentary procedure and is commonly used in meetings of all kinds of clubs and organizations.

Wikipedia defines [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_%28parliamentary_procedure%29) thus:

> In deliberative bodies a **second** to a proposed **motion** is an indication that there is at least one person besides the mover that is interested in seeing the motion come before the meeting.

and [motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_%28parliamentary_procedure%29) thus:

> In parliamentary procedure, a **motion** is a formal proposal by a member of a deliberative assembly that the assembly take certain action.

Where "second that notion" is used, my guess is it's done knowingly as a pun or unknowingly as an error.

Answer (score 3):

If this had been a parliamentary procedure, the answer would be easy: In the chambers of governmental legislative bodies, you second *motions*, not *notions*.

However, this **wasn't** a parliamentary procedure, it was an email saying, "Let's buy two of monitor X." That's hardly a formal *motion*, and I think it could be called an *idea, proposal, suggestion,* or *notion* just as easily as it could be called a *motion*. So the question becomes, can you second an *idea*, in the same way you can second a *motion* at a civic meeting?

NOAD reads:

> **second** (*verb*) [ trans. ]
>   formally support or endorse (a nomination or resolution or its proposer) as a necessary preliminary to adoption or further discussion : *Bertonazzi seconded Birmingham's nomination*.
>   • express agreement with : *her view is seconded by most Indian leaders today*.

Similarly, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/second) lists two meanings (Nos. 18 and 20):

> **second** (*verb*)
>   18. to give aid or backing to
>   20. to make a speech or otherwise express formal support for (a motion already proposed)

If you are using the verb second in sense 20, I would staunchly recommend using *motion*. However, if you are using:

> I second that notion.

to mean:

> I support that idea.

or:

> I'd back that proposal.

then I think it's an acceptable usage (although you run the risk of something thinking you've said an eggcorn, when perhaps you haven't).

Perhaps you should simply say:

> I second that idea.

to remove all doubt. If someone doesn't like that use of the verb *second*, you've got [quite a few authors](http://www.google.com/#q=%22I+second+the+idea%22&safe=off&start=0&tbm=bks) backing you up.